# Streaming data from a flutter mobile app to Firebase storage

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have an application that acquires real time data from sensors attached to the mobile device.
The app is required to stream the data to a Firebase storage while it is being acquired.
I can do this by uploading short segments as they become available, but eventually I would like all the segments from a session to be grouped in the storage.
How do I implement that? Do i create a new bucket for each session?

In addition i want this information to be saved separately for each user of the app so that one user cant access the files of another.
How do i separate the files on the storage so they are only accessible to user that uploaded them?

Answer (score 1):

Though it is possible theoretically, but Firebase storage is not designed for that purpose. You can store each segment in directory path like `root/uid/directory_id(stream_id)/` and once the streams ends you have to download every segment again and merge them and upload it back to Firebase storage. This is again a very cost intensive operation.
Ideal options are -

- Upload once stream ends
- Have your own socket server and stream there and store it to Firebase storage once streaming ends.

Comment: I cannot wait until the stream end to start the upload as the stream can be long and i would like to run a cloud function (using pub/sub subscription) to process the data once every x uploaded segments are in the storage. 
I would like to avoid needing my own server.

Will Cloud storage be more suitable for this purpose?

Comment: Then I do not think Firebase storage is the right option for you.  Why are you trying to store sensor data in the Firebase storage in the first place? It is for more of file storage.